# Take a picture horizontally using tablet PC but get vertical one

Tags: uwp, camera

Is there any way to take a picture vertically using tablet PC (or mobile phone or webcam so on...) but get horizontal one?

For example, if I take a picture horizontally, I can get 1920x1080 picture. And vertically, I can get 1080x1920 picture.

But what I need to get is 1920x1080 picture using tablet PC vertically.

Could it be possible by programming? I am developing UWP camera program with C#.

Comment: Have you solved your question by my solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the orientation of the photo when it was taken by using [System.Photo.Orientation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/props-system-photo-orientation).

When you use UWP camera relevant APIs to take photos, you could use `BitmapEncoder.BitmapProperties.SetPropertiesAsync(properties)` to set `System.Photo.Orientation` like the [Manual camera controls sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraManualControls) does it. See the `ReencodeAndSavePhotoAsync` method on [Line698](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CameraManualControls/cs/MainPage.xaml.cs#L698).